# How to connect Scala/spark with drools and how about the performance?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, drools, rule-engine

My project is switching from scala/spark to drools for rules validation, but I never used drools before, can anyone help me to answer the following questions:

1. We have about million records in hive table, and about 800 columns, with this amount of data, is there a good performance solution for the drools to be able to execute without memory outage?
2. Since the data is still in hive table, so we will still need to use scala/spark to get the records, and then feeds to drools, but with this amount of data, I'm thinking to divide these data into multiple sections, and feeds each section to drools every time in a bigger loop, is this a good way to do it? Or should I put all data into one list and feed it to drools? Will it cause program broken?
3. After the validation in drools, we need to write the results into output table, but which way is better? Write back to the scala code that calls the drools and let it write into hive table or directly write into DB2 table inside drools by calling some static method with Java jdbc? My concern is that if I write small bunch of data into hive for each loop (say if we partitioned the data into smaller lists), it will cause producing too many files to store the data, but if write data directly into DB2 in drools it will insert just one record every time, and the execution time will be longer.

That's the general questions I have, since I just started to work on POC of the solution, so I hope someone with similar experience can give me some advice on it.

Comment: You know everything about your use-case but still can not decide the correct approach. How do you expect anyone on SO to give a useful opinion with such limited information? Any comment given by us on this matter will be highly inaccurate and may  even be straight forward wrong.

Comment: Since we don't have the real data stored into hive yet, so that's why the information is limited, and unfortunately, that's also basically all info I have, since I never used drool so that's why I hope some one worked with similar requirement can give me their work flow so that I can have some general idea of what path I could choose

Comment: @user2654659 what was the outcome .. is it operation now?